# Parsing text from a linux log on windows (Adding spaces that are removed)

Tags: windows, linux, return, carriage-return

So I do a little work from time to time on Linux and today I needed to document some text files copied from the terminal window. The only problem was that I brought a linux text file over to notepad on my Win7 comp, and I noticed that all the carriage returns were removed from the text.

Is there any way to quickly add the carriage returns back in?

Comment: Use Wordpad instead of Notepad, it knows how to display lines without carriage returns.

Comment: @MarkRansom Proper text files, that is, right? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the conversion *before* the transfer:

```
unix2dos -o <pattern>
```

In case you need to keep the old files or you have only read access to them:

```
unix2dos -n <original-file> <converted-file>
```

You might not have this utility available by default in your linux distro in which case you will need to install the `tofrodos` package.

Answer (score 1):

Use Notepad++ instead of Notepad. It's free and it has a lot of functionality, including proper handling of EOL marks.